# If I want each UITableView Cell to have its own UIViewController, where is the UIViewController stored?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have already initialized a UIView and added it to the contentView of the cell in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but where should the ViewController for the view go.Am I supposed to store it in my array for the tableView?

Comment: Typically you have a view controller that manages the table and (perhaps) other UI elements that are on the screen with the table.  Why do you think cells should have individual controllers?  (Subclassing the table view cell to have special behavior is much more likely to be useful.)

Comment: Well I have a Viewcontroller that works well using the whole screen, but i wanted to make it so that I could have multiple versions of those in each tableviewcell. Is that posible with the tableviewcontroller or is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

First, you needed to create class variable to store UIViewController in each UITableViewCell. Then when table call UITableViewCell you needed to initiate or recall that custom UITableViewCell class and insert the line after define the class with

```
cell.controller = self
```

Comment: the cell reuse of an UITableView would break with this. or you must also establish a controller reuse. and anyway: it is never a good idea to have several UIViewController on screen, except it is supported by the framework (container view controller, presentModalViewController, …). To make this a valid answer, it must cover all of this.